# Resources Of Macintosh Development

Tags: macos

As I said in older questions, we(I and my friend) are trying to develop in a Macintosh IIci(System 7.5.5 68k processor), but we don't know where to start, then I'm asking here for some resources to develop on it. Thanks.

Comment: is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791166/which-languages-i-can-use-to-develop-on-a-mac-os-7-machine ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buy yourselves a copy of [Inside Macintosh](http://www.pagetable.com/?p=50) (PDF), the official developer documentation for Mac OS (classic). [Back issues](http://store.mactech.com/list.html?CREF=293) of MacTech magazine are a good high-level place to start. In the day, MacTech was *the* journal for mac developers.

It's been a lot of years, but the prominent application frameworks in classic Mac OS were Metrowerks' [PowerPlant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPlant), Symantec's [Think Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THINK_C). If you have a Metrowerks compiler, stick with PowerPlant, which has been [open-sourced](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-powerplant/).

Comment: Any version of PowerPlant that's likely to be circulating around out there will probably not build under 7.5.

Answer (score 5):

The [Macintosh Programmer's Workshop](http://developer.apple.com/tools/mpw-tools/) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to develop for older versions of MacOS like System 7.x then you may want to use Pascal. Here are possible books and tools to look at:

Books

1. Inside Macintosh: Toolbox Essentials
2. Inside Macintosh: Imaging with Quickdraw

Tools

1. Metrowerks CodeWarrior 8 (or 10): PPC & 68K, Pascal, C, C++
2. Think Pascal/Think C: 68K only, Pascal or C
3. MacsBug