# Which Languages I Can Use To Develop On a Mac OS 7 Machine?

Tags: macos

I'm emulating a Macintosh IIci running Mac OS 7.5.5 on it, but now I want to know, In which languages I can develop on it and where to get they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real Basic should also work on OS7 (Mac OS 7.6.1)
http://www.giantmike.com/reviews/realbasic.html

and actually Perl as well: http://www.perl.com/download.csp#mac

> "For Macintosh Classic users, there
>   are two ways to get Perl. MacPerl is
>   the classic Perl port to Mac OS
>   Systems 7 through 9."

Answer (score 6):

C/C++ seems like a safe bet...

You can use the [Macintosh Programmer's Workshop](http://developer.apple.com/tools/mpw-tools/)

> Macintosh Programmer's Workshop (MPW) is a product designed specifically for professional Macintosh software developers. It brings together a comprehensive collection of development tools designed to support C, C++, and assembly-language programmers who are writing software for Mac OS 7.x/8.x/9.x. MPW is an open, configurable, and scriptable development environment which provides the flexibility to support complex software development projects for 68K and Power Macintosh systems.

Answer (score 5):

Pascal is another option.

Apple had an excelent Pascal compiler for the earliests versions of Mac OS (actually, most of the API was available through Pascal calls)

Comment: Aleluia um brasileiro por aqui! +1 voto para você por causa disso amigo!

Comment: actually, most of the MacOS calls were WRITTEN IN Pascal, IIRC... this explains why all the calls assume strings made out of unsigned chars with the 1st byte being the length, and don't assume null terminated...

Comment: Much of the API was originally written in C and assembly. The pascal interface was a deliberate design decision.

Comment: [Think Pascal](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~ingemar/tp45d4/think.html#WhatIs) is a good 68k compiler with direct support for System 7 libraries and an integrated debugger.

Answer (score 1):

[HyperCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperCard) and [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applescript) are the two first that came to mind.

There's also the [Macintosh Programmer's Workshop](http://developer.apple.com/tools/mpw-tools/) and [CodeWarrior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeWarrior) IDEs for programs written in C/C++.

You'll also likely want a copy of [ResEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ResEdit) handy.

Comment: I was trying to use AppleScript before, but as I can see the syntax is different on System 7 and OS X, then you can post a link to a tutorial please? Thanks.

Comment: System 7 should come with everything you need to get started with AppleScript. I remember working through sample code when I was 10 years old on System 7. I don't remember where on the filesystem they are though...